# What is the optimal way to add constants in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, constants

When I started searching I found a few ways.

As such you are using AngularJS, you can use Constant Service as a constant can be injected anywhere including configuration calls in AngularJS application.

Also, as the name suggests, the constants are fixed, they get applied before other provide methods. See `$provide.constant()` for more details.

```js
// Storing a single constant value
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.constant('appName', 'My App');

// Now we inject our constant value into a test controller
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['appName', function TestCtrl(appName) {
    console.log(appName);
}]);
```

What is the correct approach ? Keep all the constants used within the application at the same place or we can distribute it across the places as per our need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on complexity of your app. If you have a lot of isolate pages that acts like models, I would tell you to create these pages as models and declare those constants on each model. So you will have an app module and a module for each page with its constants.

```
// page1.js
angular.module('app.page1', [])
  .constant('c1', 1);

// page2.js
angular.module('app.page2', [])
  .constant('c2', 2);

// app.js
angular.module('app', [
    'app.page1', 'app.page2'
  ])
  .constant('baseURL', '/api');
  // configurations and etc
```